# PHP execution on networked Windows server

Tags: php, filesystems, remote-access, network-connection

I’m working on an internal application for a large entity, and I need to be able to do the following:

From a web interface (hosted with Apache on Linux), constructed with PHP, connect to a Windows box that won’t have PHP installed, and move some files - live, triggered by Ajax.

I have some flexibility, but I need it to be secure.  A linked network drive is a possibility.  Another possibility if I can’t directly move the files on the Windows machine, is to have some sort of watcher on a Windows machine that will respond to some trigger.

SSH is not ideal, because I don’t want to install a server on the Windows machine.  The files are not connected to a web server, so the installed IIS on the Windows server is not necessarily helpful.

I think ideally, I’d do it over a network share - a linked directory on the remote machine, and either move the folders with PHP or if that won’t work, trigger a batch file or a Powershell script.  However, I’m not sure what to watch out for in terms of permissions / security holes.

Is there a ready made solution for this kind of thing?  Failing that; are there any general guidelines that I should consider to do this effectively - libraries, extensions, etc?

Thanks

Comment: What’s the downvote for?

Comment: You are likely downvoted because this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It is a request for software library recommendations, primarily opinion-based, and too broad. See on-topic guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Things to look at:

Windows Network File System
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/nfs/nfs-overview

With that you should be able to mount the windows directory from your linux host.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I stumbled across https://github.com/icewind1991/SMB, and I think your link will be an additional bonus.  This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for.